# BufferedReader ready method in a while loop to determine EOF?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have a large file (English Wikipedia articles only database as XML files). I am reading one character at a time using `BufferedReader`. The pseudocode is:

```
file = BufferedReader...

while (file.ready())
    character = file.read()
```

Is this actually valid? Or will `ready` just return `false` when it is waiting for the HDD to return data and not actually when the `EOF` has been reached? I tried to use `if (file.read() == -1)` but seemed to run into an infinite loop that I literally could not find.

I am just wondering if it is reading the whole file as my statistics say 444,380 Wikipedia pages have been read but I thought there were many more articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not guaranteed to read the whole input.  `ready()` just tells you if the underlying stream has some content ready.  If it is abstracting over a network socket or file, for example, it could mean that there isn't any buffered data available *yet*.

Answer (score 10):

The `Reader.ready()` method is not intended to be used to test for end of file.  Rather, it is a way to test whether calling `read()` will block.

The correct way to detect that you have reached EOF is to examine the result of a `read` call.

For example, if you are reading a character at a time, the `read()` method returns an `int` which will either be a valid character or `-1` if you've reached the end-of-file.  Thus, your code should look like this:

```
int character;
while ((character = file.read()) != -1) {
    ...
}
```